# How to manage height cell dynamically with TdBadgedCell in iOS apps?

Tags: ios, uitableview, height, dynamic

i've implemented, in my iOS ap, some TdBadgedCell (from https://github.com/tmdvs/TDBadgedCell) in a UITabView. But when I want to manage the cells' hight dynamically by using something like this example:

```
    - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
  NSString *text = [items objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

  CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(CELL_CONTENT_WIDTH - (CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN * 2), 20000.0f);

  CGSize size = [text sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:FONT_SIZE] constrainedToSize:constraint lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

  CGFloat height = MAX(size.height, 44.0f);

  return height + (CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN * 2);
}
```

the cell's width is the entire width of the cell (calculated variable "constraint" in the example below) and not the real width of the label printed on screen taking consideration of the badge's width. So, the portion of text at the end of the UILabel doesn't appear in cell when the text in too long.

How can I resolve this please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved my own problem with this portions of code:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
    MyObject *obj = [self.myObjects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *textlabel = [self getMainTextStringFromMyObject:obj];
    NSString *detailtextlabel = [self getDetailTextStringFromMyObject:obj];
    CGFloat height = MAX(CELL_TEXTLABEL_HEIGHT + [self getDetailTextSizeForString:detailtextlabel].height, CELL_ROW_DEFAULTHEIGHT);

    return height;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{ 
    MyObject *obj = [self.myObjects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *textlabel = [self getMainTextStringFromMyObject:obj];
    NSString *detailtextlabel = [self getDetailTextStringFromMyObject:obj];

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ImageOnRightCell";

    UILabel *mainLabel, *secondLabel;
    UIImageView *photo;
    TDBadgedCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) 
    {
        cell = [[[TDBadgedCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

        mainLabel = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(CELL_LABELS_MARGIN, 1.0, CELL_TEXTLABEL_WIDTH, CELL_TEXTLABEL_HEIGHT)] autorelease];
        mainLabel.tag = MAINLABEL_TAG;
        mainLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:CELL_TEXTLABEL_FONTSIZE];
        mainLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:mainLabel];

        secondLabel = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(CELL_LABELS_MARGIN, CELL_TEXTLABEL_HEIGHT, CELL_TEXTLABEL_WIDTH, 19.0)] autorelease];
        secondLabel.tag = SECONDLABEL_TAG;
        secondLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:CELL_DETAILTEXTLABEL_FONTSIZE];
        secondLabel.textColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
        secondLabel.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
        secondLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
        secondLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:secondLabel];

        float yOriginImg = (cell.contentView.frame.size.height/2.0);
        if((CELL_TEXTLABEL_HEIGHT + [self getDetailTextSizeForString:detailtextlabel].height) <= CELL_ROW_DEFAULTHEIGHT)
        {
            yOriginImg -= (CELL_IMGHEIGHT/2.0);
        }
        photo = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(CELL_LABELS_MARGIN+CELL_TEXTLABEL_WIDTH, yOriginImg, CELL_IMGWIDTH, CELL_IMGHEIGHT)] autorelease];
        photo.tag = PHOTO_TAG;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:photo];
    } 
    else 
    {
        mainLabel = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:MAINLABEL_TAG];
        secondLabel = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:SECONDLABEL_TAG];
        photo = (UIImageView *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:PHOTO_TAG];
    }

    mainLabel.text = textlabel;
    secondLabel.text = detailtextlabel;
    cell.badgeString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%g",obj.duration];

    UIImage *theImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"right_cell_icon.png"];
    photo.image = theImage;

    return cell;
}

- (NSString*) getMainTextStringFromMyObject:(MyObject*) obj
{
    return obj != nil? obj.name : nil;
}

- (NSString*) getDetailTextStringFromMyObject:(MyObject*) obj
{
    return obj.detail != nil ? obj.detail : nil;
}

- (CGSize) getDetailTextSizeForString:(NSString*) str
{
    CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(CELL_TEXTLABEL_WIDTH - (CELL_LABELS_MARGIN * 2), 20000.0f);
    return [str sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:CELL_DETAILTEXTLABEL_FONTSIZE] constrainedToSize:constraint lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
}
```